# How to compare latitude of location to a string

Tags: iphone, xcode, location

My problem is tat when i get location from locationManager it sometimes doesn't load right. So i want to check if my location is different than 0.0000000. To do so i convert coordinate to string. And then with compare that string with isEaqual to that.

```
NSMutableString *nicla=@"0.0000000";
while(true){
cLoc=appDelegate.currentLocaiton;
lat=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [cLoc coordinate].latitude];
lng=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [cLoc coordinate].longitude];

NSLog(@"Execution Time: %f lat: %p lng: %p", executionTime, lat, lng);
    NSLog(lat);
    NSLog(lng);
    NSLog(nicla);
    if([lat isEqual:nicla]){ }
    else break;
}
```

I also tryied isEaqualToString but same result, in my logs those are identicaly strings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`longitude` and `latitude` are just double values, why would you want to convert them to NSString to compare them? Just use

```
if([cLoc coordinate].latitude == 0.00) {}
```

Comment: tenx for that idea it works now, i dont know what was i thinking, but still why wouldnt it compare two strings?

Comment: Declare NSMutableString *nicla=@"0" & use lat=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)[cLoc coordinate].latitude]] ;